# ¿Por que no funciona mi login php?

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, login

Actualmente me estoy introduciendo en este mundo y estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de realizar un login. Actualmente ya tengo hecho el apartado de registro, pero no logro saber por que mi login no acaba de funcionar.

EL registro me guarda correctamente los datos en la base de datos por lo que entiendo que esta bien, pero a la hora de realizar el login simplemente le doy al boton de login y no reacciona de ninguna manera

El código siguiente corresponde a mi php -->

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="login-page">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/09/e7/9b/09e79bb010560bc75b2d24c8bb80838d.gif" class="emilia" alt="emilia">
  <div class="form">

    <form class="login-form">
      <input type="text"  placeholder="usuario"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="contraseña"/>
      <button>Inicio de Sesion</button>
      <p class="message">No estas registrado? <a href="index.html">Registrate</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<main>
      <?php

      include 'db_connect.php';
            $con = open_con();
            if (!$con) {
               die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            $usuario = utf8_decode($_POST['usuario']);
            $password = utf8_decode($_POST['password']);
            $res = $con->query("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = '$usuario' and password = '$password'");
      echo $res;
            if ($res->num_rows>0){
                printf("Usuari correcte. \n");
                close_con($con);
            }
            else{
                printf("Usuari o contrasenya incorrectes.");
            }

        ?>
    <main>

  </body>
</html>
```

Y este es mi HTML el cual creo que funciona correctamente

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

   </body>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="login-page">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/09/e7/9b/09e79bb010560bc75b2d24c8bb80838d.gif" class="emilia" alt="emilia">
  <div class="form">

    <form class="login-form" action="index.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text"  placeholder="usuario"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="contraseña"/>
      <button>Inicio de Sesion</button>
      <p class="message">No estas registrado? <a href="index.html">Registrate</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Intentaste con el botón de tipo `submit`?

Comment: en primera, prueba si tu consulta con usuario y contraseña específicos devuelve lo que deseas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tu formulario le faltan los nombres tanto para password como para usuario, tendría que estar de la siguiente forma y al button indicar que es de tipo submit:

```
<form class="login-form" action="index.php" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="usuario" value=""  placeholder="usuario"/>
     <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="contraseña"/>
     <button type="submit">Inicio de Sesion</button>
     <p class="message">No estas registrado? <a href="index.html">Registrate</a></p>
</form>
```

De esta forma ya puedes recibir los valores de usuario y password en tu script PHP:

```
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$res = $con->query("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = '$usuario' and password = '$password'");
      #echo $res;
            if ($res->num_rows > 0){
                printf("Usuario correcto. \n");
                close_con($con);
            }
            else{
                printf("Usuario contraseña incorrectas.");
            }
```

Parte de tu problema es que en el script PHP tratas de recibir "usuario" y "password" pero estos no existen ya que tus `inputs` no tienen el atributo `name=""` al enviarlos a index.php la variable `$_POST[]` no esta recibiendo nada en `$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];` y en `$password = $_POST['password'];`

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente sea que no le estas comiendo un action y un method al form, además de que el button si no mal recuerdo debe ser de tipo submit. Por otra parte, no recuerdo si en php se debe hacer el prevent del reload para los submit.

```
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="login-page">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/09/e7/9b/09e79bb010560bc75b2d24c8bb80838d.gif" class="emilia" alt="emilia">
  <div class="form">

    <form class="login-form" action="index.php" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="usuario"/>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="contraseña"/>
      <button type="submit">Inicio de Sesion</button>
      <p class="message">No estas registrado? <a href="index.html">Registrate</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<main>
      <?php

      include 'db_connect.php';
            $con = open_con();
            if (!$con) {
               die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            $usuario = utf8_decode($_POST['usuario']);
            $password = utf8_decode($_POST['password']);
            $res = $con->query("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = '$usuario' and password = '$password'");
      echo $res;
            if ($res->num_rows>0){
                printf("Usuari correcte. \n");
                close_con($con);
            }
            else{
                printf("Usuari o contrasenya incorrectes.");
            }

        ?>
    <main>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Parece mas un comentario que una respuesta. Puedes agregar el código indicando lo que mencionas sobre el `action`, `method`.

Comment: Listo, es que apenas ando haciendo mis primeros aportes y no le se hahaha.